# Can Python Scrapy module help us to make an account checker?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want to make something like this: I will have list of email and password of a certain website. I want to check that email and password work for that website. I want it to go put that email and password in email and password box of certain website. If that logged in then it will say Logged in else not logged in.

Can I built it with Python module called Scrapy?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors do you get? Refer this - [Minimum, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I haven't started it. I was just going to start that module to learn so i was asking i want to make that kind of checker.

Comment: You probably can. However, whether you should or not is another matter - good websites may detect repeated login attempts and will block you if it is clear you're trying to access an account that is not yours. Moreover, it may fall under computer misuse legislation in your country, so make sure you know the legal ramifications before doing this.

Comment: Can i built it with scrapy module? How can you suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Whether Scrapy is the best choice for your use case depends on the details you have not shared.